# What block had the most transaction fees? Why?

Tags: transaction-fees

What block had the most transaction fees? Why? How big can transactions be? What's the largest transaction (size, in bytes)?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure which block it is, but you can see it on [this graph](http://blockchain.info/charts/transaction-fees?timespan=all&showDataPoints=false&daysAverageString=1&show_header=true&scale=0&address=) from blockchain.info. It was ~305 BTCs in transaction fees. The blockchain will not tell you why the transaction fees are so high. It is probably an accident or a joke.

I believe the largest size a block can be is measured in terms of bytes, and it is 1MB. So the largest transaction can be as large as 1MB of data will let it be.

Comment: Okay... My question was which block, and which transaction...

Comment: I just found one by random searching. Over $1000 tx fee: http://blockchain.info/tx/70958529f1663c7c0e65176e719182f1d825ae6803aec4b18f7642c54fc9e4c5